# Getting the access token for facebook using curl on a linux server

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api, libcurl

I'm having a problem trying to use cURL to get the access token from Facebook on my Linux server. On my Windows machine everything works fine when I'm running PHP under XAMPP, but not in Linux.

I have installed cURL on my Linux server and am now trying to use it, but it doesn't return any information.

My code is as follows:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=278313225526998&redirect_uri=thejunction.africanbank.net/baobab/baobab.php&client_secret=$app_secret&code=$code";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: graph.facebook.com'));
$access_token = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo "access is: ".$access_token;
```

Can someone please let me know what I might be doing wrong here? It gives me the error:

```
An error occured while fetching the URI
```

I also tried using

> ```
>   $url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
>      //curl script to get content of given url
>   $ch = curl_init();
>      // set the target url
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
>   // request as if Firefox
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;   Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); 
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>   $result= curl_exec ($ch); 
>   curl_close ($ch);
>   echo "result is".$result;
> ```

and it gives me an error

```
An error occured while fetching the URI. Please retry.
```

and in my php.ini file curl is enabled, please see the picture
[image]

What might be the problem guys? please help me.

Thanks
Donald

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect_uri is wrong. It should be

1. encoded
2. with http(s)

so change

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=278313225526998&redirect_uri=thejunction.africanbank.net/baobab/baobab.php&client_secret=$app_secret&code=$code";
```

to

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=278313225526998&redirect_uri=".urlencode("http://thejunction.africanbank.net/baobab/baobab.php")."&client_secret=$app_secret&code=$code";
```

Comment: That is just a mistake that happened when i tried to format this question here.

Comment: @Dee in that case there's something wrong with other parameters

Comment: lol, i no there is defiantly something wrong, i just dont know where is that problem..

Comment: @Dee but we can't help you without these variables. add more details

Comment: Is it a good idea to post my secret code and application ID? anyway the redirect url is an intranet, not sure if that might be the thing that causes the problem.

Comment: @Dee sure it isn't. I have meant $app_id and $my_url

Comment: Seems like Facebook tries to fetch your given URI and as you sayed the URI is in your Intranet which FB can't access, which leads to the error:
An error occured while fetching the URI

Comment: @Mc yes, that's probably the problem

Comment: but why can facebook access my localhost when i'm running it on xampp and it can't access it when i'm on the same network as the intranet when i'm accessing it??

Comment: @Dee-M: I can't access that URL either

Comment: and the login function and authentification works the same, it goes to facebook and after login it redirects back to my intranet..what is the difference between the two calls?

Comment: that one that fails and this one that login the user
"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".$my_url."&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_groups"

Comment: @Dee-M: I'm not sure. Probably the first one doesn't need redirect_uri strictly